# Sending out lots of mails from Rails - what are people using these days?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

In other apps i've used ar_mailer to queue up mails and ar_sendmail to take them out of the queue in a seperate process.  I've not been massively happy with this setup: the ar_sendmail process seems to silently die fairly often, and in the default configuration mails are deleted out of the emails table when sent: i'd rather keep them for future reference and just mark them has having been sent.

I'm adding emailing into another project now (which uses rails 2.3.8) and am wondering what other solutions have people used in rails for bulk emailing?

Grateful for any advice - max

Answer (score 0):

I think the prevailing opinion is to use a bulk e-mail service like MailChimp (http://mailchimp.com) or Amazon Simple Email Service (http://aws.amazon.com/ses)

Comment: I think it depends on what type of email your sending. If it's marketing then MailChimp is pretty awesome. For transactional stuff AWS is certainly cheap or there are a huge range of different options. It's def easier to let a service like this handle the hassle in most cases though. On the other hand I have seen people have quite a lot of luck with using something like resque and manually sending the SMTP using something like the mail gem in some cases.

Comment: Sorry, should have said 'free ruby solutions' :)